# Semi-parameteric estimation

Tags: regression, causality, semiparametric, doubly-robust-estimator

I am interested in the effect of certain interventions $T$ on my value of interest $Y$, my model is,

$$Y = \tau f(T, X, Z) + g(X, Z), $$

where $f(T, X, Z) = T \times X + T \times Z$ , that is all the pairwise interaction of $T$ with the features $X$ and $Z$.
The feature $Z$ is some function of $X$s, that is exist $m(X) = Z$.

Is this a common problem? What are the standard methods of estimate $\tau$.
My intuition is to estimate $g(X, Z)$ on its own (on some part of the data), and then try to estimate the $\tau$ with the residuals and using the first part of the data to estimate $m(X)$.